# Is it possible for a matrix to not be onto or 1-1?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is it possible for a matrix to be neither onto nor 1-1?

Comment: Yes, try the zero matrix.

Comment: Actually you want the linear map defined by the matrix to be neither 1-1 (injective) nor onto (surjective). If you had considered the case of $1\times1$ matrices closely, you would have seen that $(0)$ gives multiplication by $0$, which is neither injective no surjective. In larger sizes _any_ square matrix with determinant $0$ also gives an example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A matrix isn’t a function, so the question doesn’t actually make sense. However, I understand what you mean: you’re asking whether the function $T(x)=Ax$, where $A$ is some matrix, can be neither onto nor $1$-$1$. The answer is *yes*: in fact, if you’re talking about square matrices of real numbers, the transformation is onto if and only if it is $1$-$1$. This is immediate from the [rank-nullity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem).

Comment: The question makes perfect sense, because people can understand it without flinching an eyebrow. And in fact matrices are surrounded by terminology which assumes that they are used as linear transforms. For instance, we simply say "invertible matrix", rather than "matrix denoting a linear transform which is an invertible function".

Comment: Kaz, what you say is true although "invertible matrix" at least in the case of square matrices can also be understood as "matrix which possesses an inverse" (in the appropriate group of matrices).

Comment: One of the most basic and important "tasks" a matrix fulfills is precisely as a function $\,\Bbb F^n\to\Bbb F^m\,$ , where $\,\Bbb F\,$ is a ring (or, in the most common case in basic linear algebra, a field), so I'd say we can safely see it as an actual function, in particular when later on we prove the algebra of $\,m\times n\,$ matrices over some field is isomorphic to the algebra of linear transformations between two linear spaces (of dimensions $\,m,n\,$ )...

Comment: @DonAntonio: No, it is not a function. You might as well say that a real number is a function, because so often we scale things by real numbers. Calling a matrix a function is fostering a fundamental confusion. A function is a set of ordered pairs with the specific property that makes it a function.

Comment: @Kaz: Obviously I both flinched and raised an eyebrow. Calling a matrix a function is simply incorrect. The fact that we can understand what is really meant does not change that. If a child looks at a bunch of dolphins playing in a pool and says ‘Look at the big fish!’, we know what’s meant, but we also know that the dolphins aren’t fish. The invertibility does not *a priori* have anything to do with the transformation associated with the matrix: $n\times n$ matrices over $\Bbb R$, say, form a ring, and an invertible matrix is one that has a multiplicative inverse in that ring.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, I very strongly disagree with you in this, and the generalized use of matrices in linear algebra seems to support me ( or at least so say I...:=) ), but it really is not that important, imo, and if you want to see a function from its definition in set theory then a matrix certainly and easily can fulfil that demmand: it is a subset of the cartesian product $\,F^m\times F^n\,$ , when we take a $\,n\times m\,$ matrix, just as the respective lin. transf. is a subset of the cartesian product $\, V\times W\,,\,\dim_F V=m\;,\;\dim_F W=n\,$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio: You can disagree all you like: you’re simply wrong, and you do students no service by encouraging them to use such sloppy, incorrect terminology. And no, an $n\times m$ matrix over $F$ is most certainly **not** a subset of $F^m\times F^n$. An element of $F^m\times F^n$ is an ordered pair whose first component is an $m$=tuple of elements of $F$ and whose second component is an $n$-tuple of such elements; no matrix over $F$ is a set of such ordered pairs.

Comment: Hehe...that's a good one, @BrianM.Scott, and here  your declaration stays forever (or at least for some hours, say): you've decided that I'm wrong and that's all, *even* after I explained to you otherwise. Good. Case closed.

Comment: @DonAntonio: Why would I remove a correct statement?

Comment: A matrix is a subset of $\,F^m\times F^n\,$ as much as a linear transformation is a subset of $\,V\times W\,$: both cases are a matter of convenience *and definition*. You may choose to reject this reason but I don't think it'll go away. And **now** case closed.

Comment: @DonAntonio: I’m sorry, but you are merely convincing me that either you don’t know the meaning of *subset*, or you don’t know what a matrix is.

Answer (score 4):

Consider a $m \times n$ matrix with rank $r < \min(m,n)$. This is neither onto nor one to one.

**EDIT**

To make the above point clear, in case the OP is not aware of rank, consider matrices $m \times n$ matrices of the form $$A = U V^T$$ where $U \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times r}$ and $V \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times r}$, where $r < \min(m,n)$.

To see this is not one-to-one, choose a non-zero vector $z$ orthogonal to the columns of $V$, i.e., we have $V^Tz = 0$. (Why does a non-zero $z$ exists?) Now if you consider the vector $x$ and $x+z$, we have $$V^Tx = V^T(x+z) \implies UV^Tx = UV^T(x+z),$$which clearly shows that the linear mapping is not one-to-one.

To see this is not onto, choose a vector $z$ orthogonal to the columns of $U$, i.e., we have $U^Tz = 0$. Since $z$ is linearly independent (Why?) with respect to the columns of $U$, we can never write $z = Uy$ for some $y \in \mathbb{C}^{r \times 1}$. Hence, $$z \neq U(V^Tx)$$ for all $x \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times 1}$, which clearly shows that the linear mapping is not onto.

Comment: Right. But given the question, I doubt whether OP has understood rank yet.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Added some more details. Hope it will be clear to the OP now.

Comment: Thanks alot for this post it was very helpful, its always nice to see it broken down mathematically

Answer (score 3):

Take the null matrix: $A_{ij}=0$ for any $i,j$. Of course, when you say "matrix", you really mean the associated linear transformation, $(Ax^t)^t$, yes?

Comment: Yes i do mean the linear transformation

Comment: @Clay OK. May be nicer if you write in proper terms.

Comment: im sorry, i am a beginner at matrices i just started the topic.

Comment: @Clay Sorry if I sounded harsh. It wasn't my intention. Just remember that the words "onto" and "one-one" are usually reserved for functions.